# Alternate phrase for the phrase "losing its zing"?

Tags: phrase-request

Consider the expression,

> If you eat pizza everyday, it will **lose its zing.**

I am using zing as a placeholder here. Could somebody recommend a similar expression? I am open to another sentence construction which conveys the same meaning.

Comment: Have you done any research?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I looked up the synonyms of zing, and I got the results you mentioned. I was not satisfied with the results. I thought instead of using the synonyms of zing, I should use an alternate construction of "losing its zing"

Comment: Why weren't you 'satisfied'?

Comment: Instinctively, those words did not appeal to me. For e.g. I have not heard "losing its zing"  or its synonyms, in any English movies/TV shows, that I can remember. @MichaelHarvey

Comment: Your experience is limited, and is a poor guide.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I agree. However,I don't have an alternative, except for this forum.

Comment: I would think that 'lose its **appeal**' is fairly common.

Answer (score 1):

If you eat pizza everyday,...

...it will lose its attraction.

...it will become boring.

...you will become bored with it.

...you will become blasé about it

...you will get fed up with it.

...you will get sick of it.

... etc, or even:

...you will get fat, and smell of pepperoni, and become the butt of ridicule among your friends and family, and no one will want to hang out with you anymore.

Comment: It is curious how often pizza is used in questions.

Comment: You will become "the butt".